# How to have Lists with events upon change in List

Tags: c#, events, list, generics, delegates

I'm a newbie in events.  [This example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28VS.71%29.aspx) shows that an event is invoked every time the ArrayList is changed.  I would like to know how to do it using generics.  To you implement IList or extend List?  I tried to code it but I'm stuck.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Events
{
    public delegate void ChangedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);

    public class ListWithChangedEvent<T> : IList<T>
    {
        public event ChangedEventHandler Changed;

        protected virtual void OnChanged(EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Changed != null)
            {
                Changed(this, e);
            }
        }

        public void Add(T value)
        {
            base.Add(value);
            OnChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        public void Clear()
        {
            base.Clear();
            OnChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        public T this[int index]
        {
            set
            {
                base[index] = value;
                OnChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }

    class EventListener
    {
        private ListWithChangedEvent<string> List;

        public EventListener(ListWithChangedEvent<string> list)
        {
            List = list;
            List.Changed += new ChangedEventHandler(ListChanged);
        }

        private void ListChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is called when the event fires.");
        }

        public void Detach()
        {
            List.Changed -= new ChangedEventHandler(ListChanged);
            List = null;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ListWithChangedEvent<string> list = new ListWithChangedEvent<string>();

            EventListener listener = new EventListener(list);

            list.Add("item 1");
            list.Clear();
            listener.Detach();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use ObservableCollection  and you can extend it !!
Namespace:  System.Collections.ObjectModel
Assembly:  WindowsBase (in WindowsBase.dll)

This collection fires events whenever the list is changed.(say any items are added, removed from list)

**But note :** The ObservableCollection doesnt fire events if the internal properties of objects it is holding changes. If you need that do let me know, I have extended the Observable collection to have that feature also.

Comment: Could you post that collection? I'm sure others would find it useful (although I'm probably just going to implement my own in the meantime).

Comment: Here is a very nice implementation of such a class: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5256827/830254

Comment: ObservableCollection.Clear() raises CollectionChanged event with NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs Action == Reset and empty OldItems and NewItems makes it impossible to track items that were removed from the collection