# Updating a list based on update happened to other list

Tags: c#, collections

I have `listA`, `listB`.  `listA` is subset of `listB`.  For example, 1 element is deleted and 2 elements are added to `listB`.  Then if `listA` contains the element that was deleted from listB, delete it from `listA`.  Also, `listA` should add the newly added elements.

At present I am using `foreach{ if(list.contains) }` two times. Once to add and once to delete. This will be of O(2n), which is ok.

But is there a best way to do this mostly with O(n) in LINQ/any other way?.

To be more clear:
Actually I have a list of custom class.
From which I am forming `listA` in above question(using one field of that). `ListB` is just list of string which I get from web service.
Code:

```
//First foreach loop which I was taking about.

foreach (string A in listA)
{
  if (listB.Contains(A)
   {
   }
  else
   {
      //getting items that are added to listB
   } 
}  

//Second foreach loop which i was taking about.

foreach (string A in listB)
{
  if (listA.Contains(A)
   {
   }
  else
   {
      //getting items that are deleted from listB
   } 
}
```

And then I am updating that `List<custom class>` accordingly. My main question is instead of using two `foreach` loops can I do something better?

Comment: Can you post a real code snippet please?

Comment: updated question with possible code snippet

Answer (score 1):

This might be more efficient (although that depends):

```
var notInA = listB.Except(listA).ToList();
var notInB = listA.Except(listB).ToList();
foreach (var a in notInA)
    listA.Add(a);
foreach (var b in notInB)
    listA.Remove(b);
```

Note that you need to implement a custom `IEqualityComparer<T>` if `T` is a custom class.

EDIT: so this is just synchronizing both lists. Maybe i've misunderstood the question but can't you simply:

```
listA = new List<T>(listB);
```

Comment: I am doing something similar to what you have suggested.But i liked the way you did.
As you can see from updated question that I cannot use listA = new List<T>(listB);
Instead of using two blocks of foreach can i do something better? Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use events / delegates instead of foreach ? Read a discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253481/how-to-have-lists-with-events-upon-change-in-list)

Comment: @AYK-No i cannot use them because second list i am getting from a service.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to make these lists observable. When one list is updated, trigger the CollectionChanged event, and add in some code to update your other list. You should be able to make this two way. See Observable Collections : [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx)

Furthermore, observable collections allow you to detect which kind of events occured on your collection. (Ie. Add, Remove, Replace etc.) This should help you in your process of updating the other list with the same information.

Comment: I am getting second list from service.To be more clearer i updated my question.Thanks for your inputs