# Is there a predefined event to mark that an object has been invalidated?

Tags: c#, events

I have an object which has properties. These are wired up with INotifyPropertyChanged. I also have collection properties which implement INotifyCollectionChanged. However, there is no event fired if an item already in a collection is altered.

I would like an event I can use to signal that there has somewhere been a change inside the object - is there one existing already? (it's fairly easy to do by hand, but more consitent if something already exists).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know the `System.Collections.ObjectModel` namespace has an [`ObservableCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) that does this, is that what you're going for?

Comment: I'm using that for the collection, but it doens't fire on the individual elements being edited.

Comment: According to MSDN's info on the [CollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653375.aspx) it doesn't seem to trigger. Luckily, someone else on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427471/c-observablecollection-not-noticing-when-item-in-it-changes-even-with-inotifyp/1427496#1427496) was able to get by it (as mentioned on MSDN's notes)