# wpf itemlist not updating values

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listbox

So I have three things:

- A ListBox in a Window
- A DataBase class granting me access to an ObservableList
- Contact implements INotifyChanged

In my main Window, I have three Buttons (One for new List Entry, one for editing, one for deleting an item)

I fill the list like this:

```
lbKontakte.ItemsSource = DB.GetInstance().Kontakte;
```

whereas Kontakte is a ObservableCollection

I can create a new Entry using

```
DB.GetInstance().Kontakte.Add(New Kontakt(...));
```

or remove an entry using

```
DB.GetInstance().Kontakte.Remove(...);
```

Boh actions are immediately visible in the ListBox.

If I modify a value however, I'm not using any Code. I have a TextBox which is bound to the Name field of a contact. If I make changes to it, the changes should theoretically be carried out immediately to the bound Contact Object.

However, if I do modify the text, the changes do not become visible in the ListBox. If I pause the code and take a look at the object, I can see its Name Field has correctly been changed.

How come my ListBox is not updated?

PS:
Contact does implement INotifyChanged using following Code:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, e);
        }
    }
```

and

```
public String Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Name")); }
    }
```

Edit: The Textbox is NOT part of the main Window but a Window showed as a dialog if the user clicks the edit button. The Window is then given the selectedItem casted as Kontakt in the Constructor. Bound to the Field like this:

```
<TextBox Name="txtName" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="4" Text="{Binding Path=Name}"></TextBox>
```

and

```
public KontaktAddUI(Kontakt kontaktToEdit)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.kontaktToEdit = kontaktToEdit;
        this.MainGrid.DataContext = kontaktToEdit;
    }
```

### Correct Answer in the Comments, thanks again!

Comment: your problem is `ObservableCollection` doesn't get notified if your Item Property Changed

Comment: How do you specify how to display items in your ListBox? Do you use DisplayMemberPath?

Comment: How would I go about changed my Problem then?

Comment: Botz: I only use the Binding I wrote in the question.

Comment: just check this [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5256827/1993545)

Comment: Maxx, thank you so much. If you care to write a complete answer I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Have you tried using `BindsDirectlyToSource` on the textbox, example: `<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name, BindsDirectlyToSource=True}"`

Comment: sa_ddam213: Not working either, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is `ObservableCollection` doesn't get notified if your Item Property Changed that is a known issue
 To fix this problem you need to wire up your `INotifyPropertyChanged` event to the `CollectionChanged` event from your `ObservableCollection`

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5256827/1993545) you can see an example how you could do it.