# ObservableCollection setter isn't firing when item is added

Tags: c#, mvvm, mvvm-light

I am working on a project in WPF using the MVVM Light framework. I have a `DataGrid` that is bound to an `ObservableCollection<Worker>`. As of now, when I add a new item, the `DataGrid` doesn't update and I believe it is because the setter never fires.

```
public ObservableCollection<Worker> MasterWorkerList
{
    get { return _masterWorkerList; }
    set 
    {
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Firing");
        _masterWorkerList = value; 
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => MasterWorkerList); 
    }
}
```

The messagebox never displays, even when I call this:

```
DataManager.Data.MasterWorkerList.Add(_create.NewWorker());
```

How can I get `RaisePropertyChanged` to fire so I can update the UI?

I've tried using the solutions in this post to no avail: [ObservableCollection not noticing when Item in it changes (even with INotifyPropertyChanged)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427471/observablecollection-not-noticing-when-item-in-it-changes-even-with-inotifyprop)

Any advice would be appreciated. If you need more of my code, please let me know.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You shouldn't have public setters on lists for your objects. You should rather set ut up in your constructor

```
public MyClass(){
    _masterWorkerList = new ObservableCollection<Worker>();
    _masterWorkerList.CollectionChanged += OnCollectionChanged;
}

public ObservableCollection<Worker> MasterWorkerList
{
    get { return _masterWorkerList; }
}

private void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e){
    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Firing");
    //RaisePropertyChanged(() => MasterWorkerList); 
}
```

The `CollectionChanged` event is called when you `Add` something to the ObservableCollection. If you need more ingrained control you can inherit from the `ObservableCollection` and override the `AddItem` and `RemoveItem` methods.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `CollectionChanged` to notify if an Item is added or removed.

For someone who wants to bind `ObservableCollection<T> myObservableCollection` to some control and **change UI based on item added or deleted**, you can bind `myObservableCollection.Count` directly to XAML control. In my case I needed to check if a collection is empty in XAML and set `IsVisible=False` if collection is empty.
Hence I did

```xml
<Button IsVisible={Binding myObservableCollection.Count, Converter={StaticResource emptyToBooleanConverter}} />
```

I was then passing `myObservableCollection.Count` to value converter and returning Boolean value false if the collection was empty. If you want the code of ValueConverter, I will provide it. BTW, I am using Xamarin.Forms (MAUI).