# Observablecollection.RemoveAt(item) doesn't refresh UI

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an `ObservableCollection<MyType>`, where `MyType` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` using Fody.

This collection was binded to my ui as this

```
<Grid x:Name="DetallePresupuesto" Grid.Row="2">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="{x:Static resources:Labels.SALUD_DetallePresupuesto}" Background="Bisque" TextAlignment="Center"/>
    <DataGrid 
        x:Name="DetallePresupuestoGrid" 
        Grid.Row="1" 
        Grid.ColumnSpan="1" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        Style="{DynamicResource ParadigmaNDataGrid}" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DetallePresupuesto,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ItemSelectionChangedCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=DetallePresupuestoGrid, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="AddingNewItem">
                <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding InsertItemCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="{x:Static resources:Labels.GENERAL_Item}" Width="10*" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Merlin_ConceptosFacturacion.StrDescripcionConcepto}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <controls:Search SearchParms="{Binding ElementName=EstaVentana,Path=DataContext.BusqItems}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static resources:Labels.GENERAL_Cantidad}" Width="2*" Binding="{Binding Path=NumCantidad}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static resources:Labels.GENERAL_ValorUnitario}" Width="2.5*" Binding="{Binding Path=NumValorFacturacionDigitado}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static resources:Labels.GENERAL_ValorTotal}" Width="2.5*" Binding="{Binding Path=NumValor}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="70" Header="{x:Static resources:Labels.GENERAL_BorrarItem}" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ParadigmaNDataGridHeaderStyle}">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Style="{StaticResource InLineDeleteButton}" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.DeleteCommand, ElementName=EstaVentana}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=DetallePresupuestoGrid,Path=SelectedItem}" Visibility="{Binding Merlin_ConceptosFacturacion.NumIdConcepto,Converter={cnv:decimalToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

```
private ObservableCollection<MyType> _DetallePresupuesto;
public ObservableCollection<MyType> DetallePresupuesto
{
    get {
        if (_DocumentoPresupuesto == null)
            return new ObservableCollection<MyType>();
        else
            return new ObservableCollection<MyType>(_DocumentoPresupuesto.Parent.MyType);
    }
    set { SetProperty(ref _DetallePresupuesto, value); }
 }
```

And this command that deletes one row each time

```
public void ExecuteDelete(object p)
{
    try
    {
        bool borro = false;
        MyType det = (MyType)p;
        MyType item = DetallePresupuesto.Where(x => x.NumIdTransaccion == det.NumIdTransaccion).FirstOrDefault();
        if (item != null)
        {
            DetallePresupuesto.RemoveAt(DetallePresupuesto.IndexOf(item));
            db.SetEntityState(det, EntityState.Deleted);
            db.SaveEntity(det);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ReportarInconsistencia(e.Message);
    }
}
```

My problem is when delete an item from the collection id does it  but it doesn't refresh the UI.

How can I Do to force de UI refresh ?

Comment: Tks for your suggestion b ut it was added trying to force the UI refresh.

Comment: Removing an item froma collection bound to a property does not call the setter, where presumably to fire `PropertyChanged`, wire something up tom the `CollectionChanged` event if you want to notify when items are added/removed form the collection.

Comment: Is DetallePresupuesto a collection implementing INotifyCollectionChanged? If not, it should be (like an ObservableCollection<T>).

Comment: But It is an ObservableCollection

Comment: Can I ask the reason for RemoveAt? Can you not simply do DetallePresupuesto.Remove(item);??

Comment: RemoveAt because Remove doesn't work to

Comment: @JuanPabloGomez did you check if the ObservableCollection is notifying of CollectionChanged with the Action equals to System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove?

Comment: @Krishna this looks like elements bound to something from EntityFramework, thus they might be detached objects and he needs to find the connected object (via the ID). Just a hunch though..

Comment: If you use MVVM architecture, you don't need to use the Remove method.You only need to handle the CollectionChanged in ViewModel.

Comment: @TommyMoore Yes I'm using MVVM but doesn't understand what exactly be handled. Sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: You need to define a ObservableCollection in ViewModel then bind it to your grid's DataContext property.

Comment: @TommyMoore he has an ObservableCollection in his viewmodel. He is binding to his DataContext. Please read the question and comments. There are plenty regarding OC right now.

Comment: @TommyMoore There's nothing in MVVM which says that you can't modify a Property or a Collection in the ViewModel. This is why TwoWay bindings exists. His RemoveAt use is absolutely correct.

Comment: You can always use Remove property but in this scenario it doesn't need to use that and by the way i think you refer the wrong Name. the dataGrid's name is DetallePresupuestoGrid not DetallePresupuesto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not binding to `DetallePresupuesto` in the UI. You are binding to either:

```
return new ObservableCollection<MyType>();
```

or

```
return new ObservableCollection<MyType>(_DocumentoPresupuesto.Parent.MyType);
```

For the UI to be updated you need to let the property return the list that you are removing from, i.e. the `DetallePresupuesto`. That means the getter should look something like this.

```
public ObservableCollection<MyType> DetallePresupuesto
{
    get {
        if (_DetallePresupuesto == null)
            _DetallePresupuesto = new ObservableCollection<MyType>(); //populate here

        return _DetallePresupuesto;
    }
}
```

Also, try to avoid setters for your collections.

Comment: Nice catch. Shorter: return _DetallePresupuesto ?? (_DetallePresupuesto = new ObservableCollection<MyType>());

Comment: @nkoniishvt it's a matter of preference.. [I'd rather have it in the constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17183876/238902) since the binding is created at load anyway (i.e. the lazy initalization won't be very lazy for long).