# DisplayMemberPath not displaying Property - property not found in 'ViewModel'

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

My `MainView` has a ViewModel called `MainViewModel`. `MainViewModel` creates a dialog and I want the dialogs ViewModel to be the already existing `MainViewModel`

To create the dialog from the `MainViewModel` I do

```
var MyInnerDlg = new MyInnerDlgView();
MyInnerDlg.DataContext = this;
MyInnerDlg.ShowDialog();
```

In the dialog I have a `ListBox` which I bind to a collection from my `MainViewModel`

```
public ObservableCollection<MyItemViewModel> MyList { get; set; }
```

XAML of the dialog

```
<Border Margin="5" BorderThickness="2">
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" DisplayMemberPath="{Binding MyList.Name}" />
</Border>
```

The `Name` property is in `MyItemViewModel`. With the above code I get the error:

> Name property not found in MainViewModel.

How can I refer to each of the items Name property?

Comment: Try `DisplayMemberPath="Name"` on your `ListBox`

Comment: I did but it always tries to find it on the MainViewModel.

Comment: Does your `MyItemViewModel` class have a `Name` property?

Comment: Yes it does. The error should not refer to the mainviewmodel even if it was not. Is this something to do with datacontext being 'this'?

Comment: I am using VS2013. The output window always refers parent VM ie mainviewmodel  and not MyItemViewModel. That is the whole problem

Comment: @Bijington I'm sorry, I just saw your suggestion, which I added as an answer.. If you'd like I can remove my answer and let you post it instead?

Comment: I was able to replicate the behavior you are seeing when I did not remove the Binding. Remove the binding as Bijington suggested and it should work fine. If it's still not working, make sure that you rebuilt your program.

Comment: @Default no it's fine

Answer (score 2):

`DisplayMemberPath` should probably not be a `Binding`. Change it to the property name of the property that you want to display, i.e. `"Name"`

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
```

Also, a general suggestion is [not to have public setters on lists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17183876/238902), since you can get unindented behavior. Instead, use a backing field and remove the setter.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing :

```
 <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" DisplayMemberPath="{Binding MyList.Name}">
```

To:

```
 <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" DisplayMemberPath="{Binding Name}">
```

Or try adding:

```
 <Page.Resources>
    <local:MyItemViewModel x:Key="DataContext" />   
 </Page.Resources> 

 <ListBox DataContext="{StaticResource DataContext}" ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" DisplayMemberPath="{Binding MyList.Name}"> </ListBox>
```

Usually i add a ViewModel in the xaml file itself.

```
 <Page.Datacontext>
    <local:MyItemViewModel/>   
 </Page.Datacontext>
```

Comment: Seems someone was faster with the same suggestion.

Comment: wouldn't that create a new ViewModel? It seems OP wants to refer to the already existing one.

Comment: oh ok. Didn't catch that one.