# Binding to a property that's pulling data from another property

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have an observable collection property that holds some instances of a custom class and a string property that outputs the sum of some data in the observable collection property. Like this...

```
public ObservableCollection<MyClass> MyClasses
{
    get
    {
        return _myClasses;
    }
    set
    {
        _myClasses = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("MyClasses");
        // I thought the following might work but it doesn't seem to
        OnPropertyChanged("TotalTime");
    }
}

public string TotalTime
{
    get
    {
        int totalTime = 0;

        foreach (MyClass myClass in MyClasses)
        {
            totalTime += myClass.Timespan;
        }

        return TimeSpan.FromMinutes(totalTime).ToString(@"h\:mm\:ss");
    }
}
```

As elements are added/removed from MyClasses I have a `TextBlock` that I want to bind the Text property to `TotalTime`, but it is not working.

Any ideas or tricks to make this work?

Comment: What have you tried? Provide the information. Binding to `TotalTime` seems like that should work.

Comment: The setter will not be invoked when you add/remove items. You could use the collection changed event to  publish the property changed event for TotalTime.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ObservableCollection setter isn't firing when item is added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17183812/observablecollection-setter-isnt-firing-when-item-is-added)

Comment: @musium - What about for when an item in the collection is changed? Like a string property in an item is updated?