# LongListSelector does not refresh using ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged, longlistselector

I have a simple LongListSelector without grouping option, lists some names. When a name changes in the source, the LongListSelector should have to update the list, but it shouldn't. Searching over the network I found that I have to use an ObservableCollection as data structure, beacause it has NotifyPropertyChanged event. Using an ObservableCollection instead of a List, nothing has changed: the LongListSelector does not update the items when I modify some name in the ObservableCollection.
The code is the same of this: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/LongListSelector-Demo-45364cc9

What should I modify to obtain an auto-update LongListSelector? I have to set NotifyPropertyChanged event or not? If yes, how?

Comment: Could you please post some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ObservableCollection auto updates when you change the collection itself and not a value inside one of its items.
It fires CollectionChanged when you add, remove etc... an item.

You should look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427471/observablecollection-not-noticing-when-item-in-it-changes-even-with-inotifyprop) especially simon's answer, so you can build a reusable object.