# C# binding ObservableCollection<T> with List<T>

Tags: c#, list, binding, observablecollection

I'm making an API which is will be use my chat program.

API core class have a room list like a `List<Room> Rooms_;`

API core class have a property. `public Room[] Rooms { get { return Rooms_.ToArray(); } }`

and API core class also have a property which is easily to print room list.
This property is `public ObservableCollection<Room> ObservableRooms { get { return new ObservableCollection<Room>(Rooms_); }`

Now, when room is added or removed, i coded `Add` function and `Remove` function like this.

```
Rooms_.Add(new_room);
Rooms_.Remove(room);
```

but the `ObservableRooms` dosen't change automatically.

I want to bind `ObservableRooms` property to the `Rooms_` list.

Anyone know this?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think having a property returning an **new** `ObservableCollection` with each call to get makes sense, but I'm not a WPF expert.

Comment: @Dirk No, it is a not WPF. just change value automatically :) hmm..

Comment: @Dirk an ObservableCollection has a constructor (List<T>) but is this wrong?

Comment: `ObservableCollection` just copies the elements from `List<T>` passed in constructor. It doesn't uses it internally.

Comment: The point is that an observable collection is a collection, it stores the values you add and does not rely on any external collection. Initializing it with a list/enumerable simply makes a copy of that list for internal purposes. If you change the original list then the ObservableCollection won't know that.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Ah just copies.. thanks.

Comment: @ Yes.. i will think more about this.

Comment: Are you binding anything to the ObservableCollection? Is it updating something in the UI?

Comment: Yes. in my client program, there is a listview and i want to bind listview (room infos) with OvseravableRooms.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't just manipulate the observable collection directly?

Comment: ObservableCollection will not propagate individual item changes all alone, You have to subscribe to each event. check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427471/observablecollection-not-noticing-when-item-in-it-changes-even-with-inotifyprop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are binding directly to the ObservableCollection why not manipulate the ObservableCollection directly.

```
private ObservableCollection<Room> _observableRooms

public ObservableCollection<Room> ObservableRooms 
{
    get { return _observableRooms; }
    set { _observableRooms = value; }
}
```

Then add and remove directly from ObservableRooms and your UI should update correctly.

Comment: I would also make the setter private, unless you want users of that API to change the entire collection instead of just adding/deleting items.