# DataGridView not updateing when I'm changing datasource

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have DataGridView and DataSource is List. When I'm changing elements property in that List in gridview it is shown previous. When I click on row it changes values. I'm updating list with BackgroundWorker. How update DataGridView at the same time?

Comment: ObservableCollection in place of List?

Comment: List<_Input> oldList;
 public class _Input
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Item { get; set; }
        public double Cost { get; set; }
        public double FixedPrice { get; set; }
        public double FloorPrice { get; set; }
        public string Asin1 { get; set; }
        public bool Edited { get; set; }
            }

Comment: can you try, System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<_Input> oldList instead of List<_Input> oldList?

Comment: I have tried but isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use ObservableCollection combined with `INotifyPropertyChanged` as ObservableCollection notifies only when items are added or removed but not when they are changed.

[ObservableCollection Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx)

[How to Listen to Property Changes of Items of an ObservableCollection](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/694370/How-to-Listen-to-Property-Chang)

There is also one more similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427471/observablecollection-not-noticing-when-item-in-it-changes-even-with-inotifyprop) on SO that might help you.

Answer (score 0):

modified excerpt from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.currencymanager.refresh.aspx)

```
private void RefreshGrid(object dataSource)
{
    yourGridName.Invoke((Action)delegate
    {
        var myCurrencyManager = (CurrencyManager)yourGridName.BindingContext[dataSource];
        myCurrencyManager.Refresh();
    });
}
```

Call this method whenever your background worker updates the dataSource.