# How to Bind Sum of Observable collection in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I am learning WPF so please bare my question if it is very novice! I have a collection of Items and I want to bind that collection to a Grid and bind the Sum to a textbox. Searching online I found this class that will raise event even when we make change to properties of the collection object.

[ObservableCollection not noticing when Item in it changes (even with INotifyPropertyChanged)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427471/observablecollection-not-noticing-when-item-in-it-changes-even-with-inotifyprop/5256827#5256827)

But I can't seem to make it work in my code.

Here is my code

**SaleItem**

```
public class SaleItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int Num { get; set; }
    public string ItemID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    private decimal price;
    public decimal Price
    {
        get { return price; }
        set
        {
            this.price = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Total");
        }
    }
    public int quantity;
    public int Quantity
    {
        get { return quantity; }
        set
        {
            this.quantity = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Total");
        }
    }

    public decimal Total
    {
        get { return decimal.Round(Price * Quantity, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);}
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

**Sale**

```
public class Sale : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    private Decimal _total;
    public TrulyObservableCollection<SaleItem> Items { get; set; }

    public Sale()
    {
        Items = new TrulyObservableCollection<SaleItem>();
        Items.Add(new SaleItem { ItemID = "1", Name = "Product 1", Price = 10, Quantity = 1 });
        Items.Add(new SaleItem { ItemID = "2", Name = "Product 2", Price = 10, Quantity = 1 });
        Items.Add(new SaleItem { ItemID = "3", Name = "Product 3", Price = 10, Quantity = 1 });

    }

    public Decimal Total
    {
        get
        { 
            return Items.Sum(x => x.Total);
        }
        set
        {
            _total = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Total");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public Sale Model { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Model = new Sale();
        this.DataContext = Model;            
    }



    private void btnQuantity_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Model.Items.Add(new SaleItem { ItemID = "2", Name = "Product 2", Price = 10, Quantity = 1 });

    }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local ="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Window.DataContext>
    <local:Sale />
</Window.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <DataGrid x:Name="grdItems" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"></DataGrid>
        <TextBlock x:Name="txtTotal" Text="{Binding Total}"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnQuantity" Content="Update" Click="btnQuantity_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

I am trying to test adding an item when I click on the button and also updating the quantity of the Item in the grid. If I set a break point and see the value of Total, then it is correct but somehow it is not updating on the UI. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you want to do. Is to call `OnPropertyChanged` when the collection itself has been changed. To recalculate the total. At the moment, the `Sale` class has no idea that the collection has been updated and that it needs to update its `Total` property.

One way you can do this is to check for the `NotifyCollectionChangedEvent`like this:

In your constructor for Sale():

```
public Sale()
{
 //Instantiate your collection and add items

  Items.CollectionChanged += CollectionChanged;
}
```

Then add the handler for the event:

```
public void CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
  OnPropertyChanged("Total");
}
```

If you're never going to do anything else when the collection changes apart from update the Total property. You can shorten the code further by removing the event handler and using a lambda expression instead:

```
Items.CollectionChanged += (s,e) => OnPropertyChanged("Total");
```

Unless you're ever planning on explicitly updating the `Total` yourself in the `Sale` class. The `setter` can be removed:

```
public Decimal Total
{
  get
  {
    return Items.Sum(x => x.Total);
  }
}
```

Comment: Short and sweet! Thanks!

Comment: Should i unbind the event somewhere? Or just let the GC do the job?

Comment: I'm rather interested in the case that the price of an item had changed, if you know anything good plz let me know :)

Answer (score 1):

In the Sales.cs add:

```
public void AddItem(SaleItem item)
    {
        Items.Add(item);
        OnPropertyChanged("Total");
    }
```

In MainWindow.xaml.cs call:

```
Model.AddItem(new SaleItem { ItemID = "2", Name = "Product 2", Price = 10, Quantity = 1 });
```

Instead of

```
Model.Items.Add(new SaleItem { ItemID = "2", Name = "Product 2", Price = 10, Quantity = 1 });
```

This will update the Total.

Comment: Thanks for voting up, but @JBond has provided a better solution. My solution would work with simple List<> etc. as well, but since you are using ObservableCollection<>, you could use thats benefits such as the CollectionChanged event. :)