# PropertyEventChangedHandler of ObservableCollections not firing

Tags: c#, events, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged

I've defined an Observable collection as shown below,

```
public class PropertyFieldsInExcel
{
    public string LongNames { get; set; }
    public string ShortNames { get; set; }
    public string CNames { get; set; }                              
}

static ObservableCollection<PropertyFieldsInExcel> Properties = 
    new ObservableCollection<PropertyFieldsInExcel>();
```

I have a method which changes the the value of some of the elements in that class like so,

```
public static void AutofillCell()
{            
    ((INotifyPropertyChanged)Properties).PropertyChanged += 
        new PropertyChangedEventHandler(PropertyChangedEvent);            

    Properties[i].CNames = "It works";
    Properties[i].CNames = "Ha ha ha";            

    ((INotifyPropertyChanged)Properties).PropertyChanged -= 
        new PropertyChangedEventHandler(PropertyChangedEvent);
}
```

When I assign a value to a particular element as shown above, the event does not fire. Why? What is the mistake I've committed?

The code of the event handler is like so,

```
private static void PropertyChangedEvent(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //Some code to be executed
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ObservableCollection not noticing when Item in it changes (even with INotifyPropertyChanged)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427471/observablecollection-not-noticing-when-item-in-it-changes-even-with-inotifyprop)

Comment: Are you not looking for the CollectionChanged event?

Comment: No, the collectionChanged event will not fire for sure. According to MSDN it fires only when we add, remove, replace or change the whole object. Here I'm changing a property inside the object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems:

1) `PropertyFieldsInExcel` does not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`

2) `ObservableCollection` can inform you when items are changing, but only after you manually subcribe to the changed event of all items.

The link in the comment from [Uwe Keim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/107625/uwe-keim) gives an exellent explanation with examples...

Comment: Point number 1 helped me :)