# Update ObservableCollection element not working

Tags: c#, observablecollection

I have one ObservableCollection in my ViewModel with `INotifyPropertyChanged`, say A. Now I am going to loop through A to get some elements updated.

```
public ObservableCollection<ClassA> A
{
    get
    {
        if (this.a== null)
        {
            this.a= new ObservableCollection<ClassA>();
        }
        return this.a;
    }
    set
    {
        this.a= value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged("A");// implement PropertyChangedEvent
    }
}
```

In the loop I update the values.

```
foreach (var item in MyViewModel.A)
{
    if(condition)
       MyViewModel.A.Type= "CASH";
    else
       MyViewModel.A.Type= "CHECK";
}
```

But I see the setter part is not reached. so the collection is not updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use my own method. By using generic list to retrieve the all items from Observable Collection. Then convert the generic list to the Observable Collection.

It is not the best way but so far it works out.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're trying to update the elements in the `ObservableCollection<ClassA>` and not setting the collection to a new value.  If you want a property change to occur when calling `MyViewModel.A.Type = "CASH"` then `ClassA` will need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

(EDIT: For others seeing this, check this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427471/observablecollection-not-noticing-when-item-in-it-changes-even-with-inotifyprop) - I'm not able to mark this as a possible duplicate.  You need to monitor for property changes of elements in the collection and then trigger the property change on your `ObservableCollection` manually.  The container does not do this for you.)

Comment: No, I did it. ClassA implements INotifyPropertyChanged already.

Comment: Ok.  Suggest looking at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427471/observablecollection-not-noticing-when-item-in-it-changes-even-with-inotifyprop).  They seem to be doing something similar to you.

Comment: I tried it. It is not working well as it includes ADD/REMOVE. I want replace part code.

Comment: @Bigeyes, are you sure the set method is firing and the property changed event executed when ClassA is being modified?

Comment: @dev1998. Yes. I am sure. I am thinking that can I use a list first. Update the list then convert the list to ObservableCollection. Not sure if it is okay.

Comment: One of the answers in the link from @Ewen Cochran is using a temporary list. Look at the answer by thinksomid.