# RaisePropertyChanged does not notify parent

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp, template10

We have a parent class which has a collection of children. Both classes support change notification using Template10. Change notification works within each class (ie when we update a property within the same class) as below, but we are unable to trigger change notification on the parent from the child.

```
public class ParentViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public string ParentString { get }
    public decimal? Net { get { return Total / (1 + TaxRate / 100); } }        
    public decimal? Tax { get { return Total - Net; } }
    decimal? _Total = default(decimal?);
    public decimal? Total
    {
        get
        {
            return _Total;
        }
        set
        {
            Set(ref _Total, value);
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Net));
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Tax));
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ChildViewModel> MyChildren { get; set; }
```

We find we are able to use `RaisePropertyChanged` in `ParentViewModel` to fire

```
Net { get { return Total / (1 + TaxRate / 100); } }
```

and

```
Tax { get { return Total - Net; } }
```

On `ChildViewModel` we have `ChildString`. We want to notify `ParentString` of changes to `ChildString`.

```
public class ChildViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    ParentViewModel MyParent { get; set; }
    string _ChildString = default(string);
    public string ChildString
    {
        get
        {
            return _ChildString;
        }
        set
        {
            Set(ref _ChildString, value);
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(this.MyParent.ParentString));
        }
    }
```

However `ParentString` is not updating. How do we force `ParentString` to update when `ChildString` updates?

Comment: where is `this.MyParent` assigned? and maybe [this so question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427471/observablecollection-not-noticing-when-item-in-it-changes-even-with-inotifyprop) helps

Comment: @Lei Yang MyParent is assigned by whatever method creates an instance of ChildViewModel. Thank you for the link. The accepted answer does the trick for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of `nameof` argument, when you call `ChildViewModel.RaisePropertyChanged`, you fire event on child view model.

`nameof` operator can't "change" event source. You need a way to fire parent `PropertyChanged` somehow. The easiest way is to make appropriate method in `ParentViewModel`:

```
public void RaiseParentStringChanged()
{
    RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(ParentString));
}
```

and call it from child:

```
public string ChildString
{
    get
    {
        return _ChildString;
    }
    set
    {
        Set(ref _ChildString, value);

        // assuming, that parent is assigned at this point
        MyParent.RaiseParentStringChanged();
    }
}
```

But it will be nice to throw away parent from child, if changing of `ParentString` is the only reason to bring that dependency.

Since `MyChildren` is an observable collection, you can subscribe on its `CollectionChanged` event. When new child is being added, you can subscribe on its `PropertyChanged`, and watch for `ChildString` changes to raise appropriate parent event.

It's something like this:

```
// non-related code is omitted
public class ParentViewModel: ViewModelBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<ChildViewModel> children;

    public string ParentString { get; }

    // don't do collection properties on view models
    // as get-set ones, unless you know exactly what are you doing;
    // usually you don't need to set them explicitly from outside
    public ObservableCollection<ChildViewModel> MyChildren
    {
        get
        {
            if (children == null)
            {
                children = new ObservableCollection<ChildViewModel>();
                children.CollectionChanged += ChildrenChanged;
            }
            return children;
        }
    }

    private void ChildrenChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // assuming, that only two actions ("add" and "remove") are available;
        // if you really need to nadle "reset" and "replace", add appropriate code;
        // note, that "reset" doesn't provide acceess to removed items
        switch (e.Action)
        {
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                ((ChildViewModel)e.NewItems[0]).PropertyChanged += ChildPropertyChanged;
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                ((ChildViewModel)e.OldItems[0]).PropertyChanged -= ChildPropertyChanged;
                break;
        }
    }

    private void ChildPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == nameof(ChildViewModel.ChildString))
        {
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(ParentString));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Dennis. Can you give me an example of how to subscribe to changes to the children collection?