# WPF MVVM updated source but not updating GUI

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm designing an MVVM WPF app, and one of the controls is like this,

```
<ListView Grid.Row="5"  Margin="0,5,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding temps, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

In the ViewModel, I have

```
public class IndicatorLightVM:DependencyObject
{
/*---*/
    public List<DataDev> temps { get; set;}
/*---*/

    public IndicatorLightVM(IComm icomm, int moduleAddr = 1)
    {
        iComm = icomm;
        pdm = new IndicatorLight(icomm, moduleAddr);
        temps = pdm.DataDevs;
    }
```

DataDevs has a list of DataDev as an attribute and DataDev is

```
public abstract class DataDev: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int ModuleAddr { get; set; }
    private double _value;
    public double Value {
        get
        {
            return _value;
        }
        set
        {
            _value = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Value");
        }
    }
/*---*/
}
```

Then I call a method updating the Value of Datadev. When I tracked into the code, Values are changed but the UI is not updating.

```
public override CommResults ReadData()
    {
        channelselect = DataDevs.Count(d => d.isTest);
        byte[] recvbuf = new byte[channelselect * 2+7];
        byte[] sendbuf = new byte[7];
        sendbuf[0] = Convert.ToByte(ModuleAddr % 256);
        sendbuf[1] = 0X07;
        sendbuf[2] = 0X07;
        sendbuf[3] = BoolsToBytes()[0];
        sendbuf[4] = 0X00;

        CommResults result = GetCommData(sendbuf, recvbuf, channelselect * 2+7);
        if (result != CommResults.OK)
        {
            return result;
        }          
        AnalyseData(recvbuf);
        return CommResults.OK;
    }

    private void AnalyseData(byte[] recvbuf)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < channelselect; i++)
        {
            byte ss = Convert.ToByte(recvbuf[i * 2 + 6] & 0xF8);
            if (Convert.ToInt32(ss) == 0xF8)
            {
                DataDevs.Where(x=>x.isTest).ToArray()[i].Value = (-((256 - recvbuf[i * 2 + 6]) * 256 - recvbuf[i * 2 + 5]) * 0.0625);
            }
            else if (Convert.ToInt32(ss) == 0)
            {
                DataDevs.Where(x => x.isTest).ToArray()[i].Value = ((recvbuf[i * 2 + 6] & 7) * 256 + recvbuf[i * 2 + 5]) * 0.0625;
            }
        }
    }
```

Sorry for missing code.

Comment: `Then I call a method updating the Value of Datadev.` Where is it ? Please add the code to your question.

Comment: Why does your "View-Model" derive from `DependencyObject` ? You should rather derive from an abstract base class which implements INotifyPropertyChanged. You might also want to add a notifier for your list, in case you exchange it with another list object.

Comment: How does the UI access the `Value` property. I don't see `DisplayMemberPath`, so I don't know whether you just have a `ToString` override in your `/*---*/` part of code...

Comment: It would be better if you create a [`MCVE`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). There are a lot of details missing.

Comment: @grek40 yes, I override ToString

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you don't directly use the `Value` in your UI.

Solution:

```
<ListView
    Grid.Row="5"
    Margin="0,5,0,0"
    ItemsSource="{Binding temps, Mode=TwoWay}"
    DisplayMemberPath="Value"/>
```

Your current approach goes the following route:

```
Value -> ToString -> GUI
```

So the GUI doesn't know it has to update on `Value` change. WPF will only react to property change notifications when it is aware of the property being used in the GUI and that doesn't work via `ToString` but only with `...Path="PropertyName"` or with Bindings targeting the property.

Comment: Gods! Thank you! I've been stuck for a day. Thanks so much!

Answer (score -1):

Change the type of the `List` to an `ObservableCollection`.

```
public class IndicatorLightVM:DependencyObject
{
    /*---*/
    public ObservableCollection<DataDev> temps { get; set;}
    /*---*/
}
```

`ObservableCollection` - Represents a dynamic data collection that provides notifications when items get added, removed, or when the whole list is refreshed.

**Update**

You need a "custom" `ObservableCollection`. This question is a possible duplicate of this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427471/observablecollection-not-noticing-when-item-in-it-changes-even-with-inotifyprop) answer. To get there you still need and `ObservableCollection`. By implementing the answer there you'll solve your issue.

Comment: He's not adding or removing an element. He's modifying the content of an element which already has a notifier.

Comment: I've tried ObservableCollection, still not working. I thought ObservableCollection is used when you removing/adding elements from/to a list. Yeah, I'm doing what Blacktempel said.

Comment: At least the accepted answer in the linked SO question doesn't really address the issue of this question. So if you think its a duplicate, you should mention which answer would specifically be the solution.

Comment: You are correct @grek40, thank you for pointing it out. The answer that would help this question is the [second one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5256827/3164614). Because that answer provides the way to update all the bindings.