# Sorting an ObservableCollection after editing a property of an item

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, prism, observablecollection

I'm trying to bind an `ObservableCollection<T>` to a `DataGrid` in WPF.
Below the `DataGrid`, there are fields to edit the currently selected item from the `DataGrid`like so:

[image]

So the generic `T` of the `ObservableCollection<T>` has the following properties:
- Title (Überschrift)
- Description (Beschreibung)
- Path (Pfad)

and it also has a property `Reihenfolge` which means `Order`.

With the yellow arrows, I want to be able to modify the order of the entries.

Unfortunately, the `ObservableCollection` doesn't have an `OrderBy`-method...

---

I've tried the following:

In XAML I have defined a `CollectionViewSource` like this:

```
<CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Bilder}" x:Key="Pictures">
    <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Reihenfolge" />
    </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

And I have binded the `DataGrid` to this `CollectionViewSource`

```
<DataGrid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"
          Name="PictureDataGrid"  
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Pictures}}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
          IsReadOnly="True" 
          CanUserAddRows="false" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedBild}"  
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
          VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
 ...
```

In the ViewModel, I have these properties:

```
public ObservableCollection<BildNotifiableModel> Bilder { get; set; }
public BildNotifiableModel SelectedBild { get; set; }
```

and two methods which are called with `DelegateCommands` that update the order

```
 private void MoveSeiteUp()
 {
     const int smallestReihenfolge = 1;
     if (this.SelectedBild.Reihenfolge > smallestReihenfolge) {
            var bildToSwapReihenfolgeWith = this.Bilder.Single(b => b.Reihenfolge == this.SelectedBild.Reihenfolge - 1);
            this.SelectedBild.Reihenfolge--;
            bildToSwapReihenfolgeWith.Reihenfolge++;

            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(this.Bilder));
        }
    }

    private void MoveSeiteDown()
    {
        if (this.SelectedBild.Reihenfolge < MaxAllowedImages) {
            var bildToSwapReihenfolgeWith = this.Bilder.Single(b => b.Reihenfolge == this.SelectedBild.Reihenfolge + 1);
            this.SelectedBild.Reihenfolge++;
            bildToSwapReihenfolgeWith.Reihenfolge--;

            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(this.Bilder));
        }
    }
```

The order gets updated correctly, but unfortunately, the view doesn't reflect the changes... only after closing and reopening the view, the entries in the DataGrid are in the correct order.

- What am I doing wrong here?
- How can I make the DataGrid update, when changing the order?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Instead of providing a translation of all your code, why not post a translated version here?

Comment: To answer your question: [check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5256827/4634044)

Comment: The `ObservableCollection<T>` class has a [Move](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1.move?view=netframework-4.7.2) method which you should be able to use here.

Comment: @ChristianMurschall this helped, thank you! If you add this as an answer, I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the CollectionView doesn't listen for the PropertyChanged-Events from its elements and also `RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(this.Bilder));` dosen't work because the CollectionView is not really changed.

I would recomend to create the CollectionView in code via `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(list)`. So you can control the CollectionView from your model and call `ICollectionView.Refresh` if needed.

Answer (score 0):

In your Methods, create a new Collection and add it to "Bilder". Just raising the PropertyChanged will execute an evaluation for referential equality. If it is the same - which it will be, if you just move items inside around - it will not update the DataGrid.

If you are not using the ObservableCollections attributes, like automatically updates, when items are added or removed, you might also change it to a "normal" List.

```
private void MoveSeiteUp()
{
 const int smallestReihenfolge = 1;
 if (this.SelectedBild.Reihenfolge > smallestReihenfolge) {
        var bildToSwapReihenfolgeWith = this.Bilder.Single(b => b.Reihenfolge == this.SelectedBild.Reihenfolge - 1);
        this.SelectedBild.Reihenfolge--;
        bildToSwapReihenfolgeWith.Reihenfolge++;

        this.Bilder = new ObservableCollection<BildNotifiableModel> (this.Bilder);

        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(this.Bilder));
    }
}

private void MoveSeiteDown()
{
    if (this.SelectedBild.Reihenfolge < MaxAllowedImages) {
        var bildToSwapReihenfolgeWith = this.Bilder.Single(b => b.Reihenfolge == this.SelectedBild.Reihenfolge + 1);
        this.SelectedBild.Reihenfolge++;
        bildToSwapReihenfolgeWith.Reihenfolge--;

        this.Bilder = new ObservableCollection<BildNotifiableModel> (this.Bilder);

        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(this.Bilder));
    }
}
```