# Maui Custom Entry Behavior is blocking blocking Set call on ViewModel

Tags: maui, viewmodel, setter, behavior

I have created a custom behavior for the Entry control that allows a collection of Entry controls to provide a single-digit code input field that moves the cursor to the next field ( to the right ) when a value is entered, and to the previous field ( to the left ) when a value is deleted. This mostly works. There are still some bugs to work out in the actual behavior. The issue I am trying to resolve right now is that the string array that is the backing field in the ViewModel is not getting set calls, which means I can't raise property change notifications.

The custom behavior code is listed below..

```
public class AutoFocusBehavior : Behavior<Entry>
{
    private string previousText = string.Empty;

    public static readonly BindableProperty EntryTextChangedProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(EntryTextChanged),
                                typeof(EventHandler<TextChangedEventArgs>),
                                typeof(AutoFocusBehavior),
                                null);

    public event EventHandler<TextChangedEventArgs> EntryTextChanged;

    protected override void OnAttachedTo(Entry entry)
    {
        base.OnAttachedTo(entry);

        entry.Focused += OnEntryFocused;
        entry.TextChanged += OnEntryTextChanged;
    }

    protected override void OnDetachingFrom(Entry entry)
    {
        base.OnDetachingFrom(entry);
        entry.Focused -= OnEntryFocused;
        entry.TextChanged -= OnEntryTextChanged;
    }

    private void OnEntryFocused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is Entry entry)
        {
            // Store the previous text if it's not null or empty
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(entry.Text))
            {
                previousText = entry.Text;
            }

            // Select all text when the Entry is focused
            entry.SelectionLength = entry.Text?.Length ?? 0;
        }
    }

    private void OnEntryTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is Entry entry)
        {
            if (e.NewTextValue.Length == 0 && e.OldTextValue.Length == 1)
            {
                // If the user deletes a character, move focus to the previous entry
                if (!MoveFocusToPreviousEntry(entry))
                {
                    // If it's the first entry, do not move focus
                    entry.Text = string.Empty;
                }
            }
            else if (e.NewTextValue.Length == 1)
            {
                // If the text length is 1, move focus to the next entry and clear the current entry
                entry.Unfocus();
                MoveFocusToNextEntry(entry);
            }

            EntryTextChanged?.Invoke(sender, e);
        }
    }


    private void MoveFocusToNextEntry(Entry currentEntry)
    {
        // Find the parent stack layout containing all the Entry elements
        if (currentEntry.Parent is StackLayout stackLayout)
        {
            // Get the index of the current Entry
            int currentIndex = stackLayout.Children.IndexOf(currentEntry);

            // Move focus to the next Entry if it exists
            if (currentIndex < stackLayout.Children.Count - 1)
            {
                Entry nextEntry = (Entry)stackLayout.Children[currentIndex + 1];
                nextEntry.Focus();
            }
        }
    }

    private bool MoveFocusToPreviousEntry(Entry currentEntry)
    {
        // Find the parent stack layout containing all the Entry elements
        if (currentEntry.Parent is StackLayout stackLayout)
        {
            // Get the index of the current Entry
            int currentIndex = stackLayout.Children.IndexOf(currentEntry);

            // If it's the first Entry and the text is empty, do not move focus
            if (currentIndex == 0 && string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentEntry.Text))
            {
                return false;
            }

            // Move focus to the previous Entry if it exists
            if (currentIndex > 0)
            {
                Entry previousEntry = (Entry)stackLayout.Children[currentIndex - 1];
                previousEntry.Focus();
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

The XAML that this code is bound to is

```html
<StackLayout x:Name="EntryStack" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Spacing="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0, 10">
  <!-- Code Entry Boxes -->
  <Entry WidthRequest="40" Text="{Binding CodeDigits[0], Mode=TwoWay}" Keyboard="Numeric" MaxLength="1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center">
    <Entry.Behaviors>
      <b:AutoFocusBehavior EntryTextChanged="{Binding EntryTextChangedCommand}" />
    </Entry.Behaviors>
  </Entry>
  <Entry WidthRequest="40" Text="{Binding CodeDigits[1], Mode=TwoWay}" Keyboard="Numeric" MaxLength="1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center">
    <Entry.Behaviors>
      <b:AutoFocusBehavior EntryTextChanged="{Binding EntryTextChangedCommand}" />
    </Entry.Behaviors>
  </Entry>
  <Entry WidthRequest="40" Text="{Binding CodeDigits[2], Mode=TwoWay}" Keyboard="Numeric" MaxLength="1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center">
    <Entry.Behaviors>
      <b:AutoFocusBehavior EntryTextChanged="{Binding EntryTextChangedCommand}" />
    </Entry.Behaviors>
  </Entry>
  <Entry WidthRequest="40" Text="{Binding CodeDigits[3], Mode=TwoWay}" Keyboard="Numeric" MaxLength="1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center">
    <Entry.Behaviors>
      <b:AutoFocusBehavior EntryTextChanged="{Binding EntryTextChangedCommand}" />
    </Entry.Behaviors>
  </Entry>
  <Entry WidthRequest="40" Text="{Binding CodeDigits[4], Mode=TwoWay}" Keyboard="Numeric" MaxLength="1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center">
    <Entry.Behaviors>
      <b:AutoFocusBehavior EntryTextChanged="{Binding EntryTextChangedCommand}" />
    </Entry.Behaviors>
  </Entry>
  <Entry WidthRequest="40" Text="{Binding CodeDigits[5], Mode=TwoWay}" Keyboard="Numeric" MaxLength="1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center">
    <Entry.Behaviors>
      <b:AutoFocusBehavior EntryTextChanged="{Binding EntryTextChangedCommand}" />
    </Entry.Behaviors>
  </Entry>
  <Entry WidthRequest="40" Text="{Binding CodeDigits[6], Mode=TwoWay}" Keyboard="Numeric" MaxLength="1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center">
    <Entry.Behaviors>
      <b:AutoFocusBehavior EntryTextChanged="{Binding EntryTextChangedCommand}" />
    </Entry.Behaviors>
  </Entry>
  <Entry WidthRequest="40" Text="{Binding CodeDigits[7], Mode=TwoWay}" Keyboard="Numeric" MaxLength="1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center">
    <Entry.Behaviors>
      <b:AutoFocusBehavior EntryTextChanged="{Binding EntryTextChangedCommand}" />
    </Entry.Behaviors>
  </Entry>
</StackLayout>
```

The Property the view model is binding to is ...

```
 public string[] CodeDigits
 {
    get { return _codeDigits; }
    set
    {
        if (_codeDigits != value)
        {
            _codeDigits = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(CodeDigits));
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(IsVerifyButtonEnabled));
        }
    }
 }
```

I have tried a number of different things to get the setter fired, including adding the BindableProperty for the behavior and manually firing the EntryTextChanged event from the behaviors own OnEntryTextChanged handler. I am missing something fundamental here. Any help/guidance is appreciated :-)

Comment: You could also try using [CollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/?view=net-maui-8.0) or [BindableLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/bindablelayout?view=net-maui-8.0) and set the ItemsSource to a custom "ObservableCollection". If you have any question, free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Your setter is not called because it belongs to `CodeDigits` property, not to the strings contained in it.

You may try using `ObservableCollection` instead of `string[]`, but I'm not sure it would change something.

I see two ways.

If you know how many entries you need, let's say 8, you can use 8 `string` properties and call RaisePropertyChanged for each of them.

Otherwise, you have to create a more complex object that implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and has a `string` property and then you store 8 of these objects in the array.

Answer (score 0):

The elements in **CodeDigits** have been changed though the setter is not fired. The setter will fire only when the entire **CodeDigits** changes.

If you want to raise property changed event in ViewModel, one of the easiest way I think is using Entry's **TextChanged** event.
For convenience, you could use [EventToCommandBehavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/behaviors/event-to-command-behavior) from .NET MAUI Community Toolkit.

```
        <Entry WidthRequest="40" Text="{Binding CodeDigits[0], Mode=TwoWay}" Keyboard="Numeric" MaxLength="1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" 
           >
            <Entry.Behaviors>
                <b:AutoFocusBehavior EntryTextChanged="{Binding EntryTextChangedCommand}" />
                <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior
                EventName="TextChanged"
                Command="{Binding MyEntryTextChangedCommand}" />
            </Entry.Behaviors>
        </Entry>
```

And in viewModel, you could RaisePropertyChanged.Because the elements in **CodeDigits** have been changed, you don't have to RaisePropertyChanged for CodeDigits.

```
    public Command MyEntryTextChangedCommand
    {
        get => new Command(() =>
        {
            //Add the logic here
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(IsVerifyButtonEnabled));
        });
    }
```

Besides, you could also refer to [Consume a .NET MAUI behavior with a style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/behaviors?view=net-maui-8.0#consume-a-net-maui-behavior-with-a-style), which could make your code more clean.

Another community also mentioned using **ObservableCollection**.I am not quite sure if it works. Because the Setter method of ObservableCollection will not be fired when a property of an item changes. Please refer to this thread : [C#, Xamarin Forms - ObservableCollection of custom Object updates but does not fire property changed events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75007995/c-xamarin-forms-observablecollection-of-custom-object-updates-but-does-not-f). Also, you have to change the UI a bit more. You may use a CollectionView or BindableLayout and set the ItemsSource for it.

Please let me know if you have any question.