# Simple Listbox Databinding in IronPython and WPF

Tags: wpf, windows, user-interface, listbox, ironpython

Bear with me, I'm new to GUI Programming, IronPython, WPF and .NET. However, I am fairly familiar with Python. I have read through many tutorials regarding databinding such as DevHawk but these are too advanced for me.

Issue: I'd like to display in a Listbox control the file paths from a python list that can be modified, add or remove entries. The first part I have accomplished following the tutorials.

[image: Listbox with files listed]

However, when I update the file list, the listbox control does not update with the new files and when I attempt to manipulate the listbox the app excepts with the following debug message from VS2012:

> Add File Click ['C:\test\Employment_Law_Alert_03_28_2012.pdf',
>   'C:\test\Graph Paper .10in Cartesian c-i-110.pdf', 'C:\test\Greek
>   Alphabet Symbol.pdf', 'C:\test\CNN Money Tipping Guide - How Much to
>   Tip.pdf']
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>    SystemError: An ItemsControl is inconsistent with its items
>   source.   See the inner exception for more information.

Obviously, the listbox.ItemSource is out of sync with the python list. How does one update the two?

Below are the sample codes...

Python:

```
def addFile(self, sender, e):
    ... # Some files added to self.fileInList
    self.listBoxPDFs.ItemsSource = self.fileInList
```

XAML:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBoxPDFs" Margin="2, 2, 2, 2">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding BindsDirectlyToSource=True}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

UPDATE: I found one work around, but surely there is a better way?

```
def addFile(self, sender, e):
    ... # Some files added to self.fileInList
    self.listBoxPDFs.ItemsSource = [] # Clear the listbox first.
    self.listBoxPDFs.ItemsSource = self.fileInList # Then rebind.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want `ListBox` to update when new items are added to `ItemsSource` collection, you need to use `ObservableCollection<T>`. Alternatively, you can [force an update manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253036/a-better-way-of-forcing-data-bound-wpf-listbox-to-update), but it will be much slower, especially if there are many items.